# Simple Regular Expression to include % and _ symbols

Tags: regex, vb.net

I currently have `(\d{1,})(,\d{1,})*` as a regular expression to accept a string of numbers separated by commas.

How can I modify this to make it accept "wildcards" symbols such as `%` and `_` so the following would also be valid:

- `188%,45311,423424,_343%`
- `%`
- `_132`
- `%123%`

I don't think this is a hard regex to write, just that I don't really know how to write them. `[%_0-9,]*` kinda does it, but it is not as concrete as I would want it to be.

Comment: well ,concrete enough to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I modify this to make it accept "wildcards" symbols such as `%` and `_`

Instead of just `\d`, accept a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), namely `[\d%_]`:

```
[\d%_]+(,[\d%_]+)*
```

<sup>*Hint: `{1,}` is equivalent to `+` and the first set of parentheses was superfluous.*</sup>

Further modifications to the expression depend on whether you define things like `_,_,_,_` as valid or not (I guess you do).

If you want to rule out partial matches, add anchors `^` and `$` to the beginning and the end of the regex, respectively.

Comment: I would say the underscore expression you mentioned is valid, but I do not see anybody using that. So from your suggestion, the + means that it would accept at least 1 of a character class defined as [digit, % or _] and then it would accept 0 or more sets of a comma and the character class from before. Am I understanding it right? 

What would be a partial match in this case?

Comment: Yes, that's right. `+` and `*` are shorthands for `{1,}` and `{0,}`. A partial match would be the string `"invalid suff here 12,3,4,_2,%"`. The expression `[\d%_]+(,[\d%_]+)*` matches that string partially (at the end). If you want to enforce a full-string match, you must use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).